# how to verify that ObjectContext.CommandTimeout value is actually working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I believe I am running into an issue which I believe is a server issue, however, I was told to try to increase the Timeout value like this:

```
    using (var db = new LEAP_Professional_DAL.DAL.LEAPEntitiesDAL())
    {

   Int32 timeoutVal = Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["commandTimeValue"]);

    ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = timeoutVal;

    ...
    }
```

I'm just wondering if there is a way to verify if this is working as I'm expecting?  The current value is set at 60 seconds.

Is there anyway to verify that the `CommandTimeout` is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it to 1 second and execute `WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02'`.